# Typescript recursion function undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

For the recursion function in typescript/javascript, I understood that 'this' context is tricky and I tried to use arrow function to avoid context change but it still doesn't work.

The code is shown as below:

```
export interface Item {
    label: string;
    items?: Item[];
}

export class BannerTreeModel {
    rootItems: Item[] = [];

    getMaxDepthSubtree(root_item: Item) {
        let max_depth = 0;
        if (root_item.items) {
            root_item.items.forEach((child) => {
               max_depth = Math.max(max_depth, this.getMaxDepthSubtree(child));
            });
        }
        return ++max_depth;
    }
}
```

And to call the function, the code is below:

```
let model: BannerTreeModel = new BannerTreeModel();
model.rootItems = [{ label: 'item1', items: [{label: 'item2'}, {label: 'item3'}] }];
model.getMaxDepthSubtree(model.rootItems[0]);
```

In debug mode, `this` in `this.getMaxDepthSubtree(child))` is undefined, thus I got an error with *`undefined function getMaxDepthSubtree`* in this line. Any suggestion how to solve it?

Comment: Is the function part of an object? How are you calling the function?

Comment: you are setting max_depth to 0 each time?. Try setting it as a global variable.

Comment: @Joel No. Just no. No need for globals here.

Comment: @deceze by global i mean, outside of this functions scope. she's resetting the counter each time. i'm guessing that is not what she wants. (Since she is adding +1 to it each iteration in the return).

Comment: It's a member function of an object. I call the function via object_name.getMaxDepthSubtree(item)

Comment: Give us the full example that we can run.

Comment: @deceze oh, nvm.. i jumped the gun there. I didnt realize she added `max_depth` to the result of Math.max.. mb.

Comment: @deceze Done with the basic example.

Comment: @JenniferQ the code you posted does not give me any errors when I run it

Answer (score 0):

Inside forEach, `this` refers to the global `window` object.

Try storing the class context in a variable `_this`:

```js
export class BannerTreeModel {
    rootItems: Item[] = [];
    var _this = this;

    getMaxDepthSubtree(root_item: Item) {
        let max_depth = 0;
        if (root_item.items) {
            root_item.items.forEach((child) => {
               max_depth = Math.max(max_depth, _this.getMaxDepthSubtree(child));
            });
        }
        return ++max_depth;
    }
}
```